# C++ How to use shared_ptr with tr1::function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am binding a member function object and I'm receiving a std::tr1::function. 
Now I am using a pointer to that std::tr1::function inside another C++/CLI project, where I faced a issue of object destruction and undefinied behavior (because using a pointer to std::tr1::function). To avoid that, I am trying to use a shared_ptr instead. How can I do that?

ITestInterface.h

```
#pragma once

class ITestInterface
{
public:
  virtual void Test() = 0;
};
```

TestNativeClass.h

```
#pragma once
#include <functional>
#include "ITestInterface.h"
#include <memory>

class TestNativeClass
{
public:
  TestNativeClass(void);

private:
  void testHandle(std::shared_ptr<ITestInterface> test);

private:
  std::tr1::function<void __cdecl (std::shared_ptr<ITestInterface> test)> m_datahandle;
};
```

TestNativeClass.cpp

```
#include "TestNativeClass.h"
#include <memory>


TestNativeClass::TestNativeClass(void)
{
  m_datahandle = std::tr1::bind(&TestNativeClass::testHandle, this, std::tr1::placeholders::_1);
  // This below doesn't work and says:error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'std::tr1::function<_Fty>' to 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>'
  std::shared_ptr<std::tr1::function<void __cdecl (std::shared_ptr<ITestInterface> test)>> test = std::shared_ptr<std::tr1::function<void __cdecl (std::shared_ptr<ITestInterface> test)>>(m_datahandle);
}

void TestNativeClass::testHandle(std::shared_ptr<ITestInterface> test)
{

}
```

Comment: If you have `std::shared_ptr` you also have `std::bind` and `std::function`. Why not use the actual standardized variants, instead of the old and obsolete ones from `tr1`?

Comment: You're right, god damn I missed that. I thought the compiler didn't support it and I checked that. Doesn't fix my issue tho.

Comment: And I really don't see the reason for `test` here, or why it needs to be a shared pointer. Not to mention that a `std::function` (or indeed `std::tr1::function`) object is not a a pointer and can't be converted to a pointer, and thus can't be used to construct an `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: I used `test` here because in my real app, I have a function with a `std::shared_ptr` parameter.

Comment: Well, if so.. perhaps you can help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57323816/c-cli-how-do-i-ensure-that-a-object-doesnt-get-deleted-while-its-member-func/57323940#57323940) one.

Comment: But you're supposed to pass a (shared) pointer to `ITestInterface`, that doesn't mean the `std::function` object needs to be a (shared) pointer. It seems you're misunderstand something, but I don't know what.

Comment: A `std::shared_ptr` must be constructed with a pointer to an object that was constructed with `new`. That, after all, is what shared_ptr is all about: to automatically have it `delete` something that was previously `new`ed. Since there's nothing in the shown code that constructs anything with `new`, that, obviously, is why you cannot construct your `std::shared_ptr`. P.S. Have you considered simply installing a current Linux distribution, with the current version of gcc, a modern C++ compiler, instead of suffering with that ancient compiler?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik understood. Thank you. I wish I could, but the company I'm working in is using this old crap...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if you look at the link I commented, you might understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: As long as the `m_datahandle` is valid (which should be throughout the life-time of the `TestNativeHandle` object) you don't need to use shared pointers for the function. The problem is the `ITestInterface` object, you could need a shared pointer for that to make sure its life-time doesn't end before you use it (and definitely when calling the `testHandle` function). But the function itself and the `m_datahandle` object is really not connected to the `ITestInterface` class or its children.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in my specific case my `TestNativeClass` object and thus, also `m_datahandle` get destroyed while my C++/CLI object is currently executing a member function of the `TestNativeClass` object (bound via std::bind too). This behavior is a race condition due to multithreading.

Comment: Then perhaps you should have a `std::shared_ptr` of the `TestNativeClass` object instead?

Comment: I'm not holding the object, just the address of the std::function. Tho somehow, I'd need to not copy my object into the std::function, I would rather need to put a shared_ptr into the std::function. No clue how. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57323816/c-cli-how-do-i-ensure-that-a-object-doesnt-get-deleted-while-its-member-func/57323940?noredirect=1#comment101138638_57323940)

Comment: BTW: `function<void __cdecl (int)>` is incompatible with `function<void __cdecl (std::shared_ptr<ITestInterface>)>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 jep, just saw it. Forgot to correct it.